# Unable to convert Uint8 ArrayBuffer (of image) to base64 buffer for saving in Mongo database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, fetch, buffer

I trying to download image from url(that i get from client-side) on server side and then store it in mongo database.

```
router.post('/fetchbyurl'), async (req,res) => {
  const mime = require('mime-kind')
  const base64ArrayBuffer = require('base64-arraybuffer')
  resData = await fetch(req.body.url,{ 
    mode: 'no-cors'
    })

  const data = await resData.arrayBuffer() //Uint8 arrayBuffer 
  console.log(mime(data)) //mime: 'image/jpeg'
  const base64str = base64ArrayBuffer.encode(data) //Base64 buffer string

  const arrayBuffer = Buffer.from(base64str) //this is not rendering image.
  console.log(mime(arrayBuffer)) // null
}
```

I am trying to render like this:

```
<img src = "data:image/jpg;base64,arrayBuffer>
```

I need help to figure out, how to save that image in base64 arraybuf so that I can save it in mongodb.

Comment: I am still confused by the difference between arrayBuffer and Uint8 buffer

Answer (score 0):

So its working now, all I did is changed the arrayBuffer line like this:

```
const arrayBuffer = Buffer.from(base64str.toString('ascii'), 'base64');
```